# Требуется помощь в оптимизации текущего решения задачи

Tags: c++

Условие задачи сайт e-olymp.com

Лифт

В центре города Нью-Донецк построили небоскреб с огромным числом этажей. Он имеет и подземную часть, количество этажей которой также невероятно велико. Человек, который входит с улицы в этот небоскреб, попадает на этаж с номером 0. Этажи, расположенные выше него, имеют положительные номера, ниже - отрицательные. В небоскребе имеется лифт. Однако по определенным причинам на некоторых этажах он не может останавливаться. В лифте имеется две кнопки - "вверх" и "вниз". При нажатии кнопки "вверх" лифт поднимается до ближайшего этажа, на котором он может остановиться. При нажатии кнопки "вниз" - опускается до ближайшего такого этажа. Многократное нажатие на кнопку приводит к тому, что лифт выполняет требуемое действие соответствующее количество раз, не останавливаясь на промежуточных этажах. Мальчик Вася решил покататься на этом лифте. Он вошел в лифт на нулевом этаже и стал нажимать на кнопки.

Напишите программу для нахождения пути, который проделает Вася.

Входные данные

В первой строке заданы два целых числа K и N (0 ≤ K, N ≤ 10^5) - количество этажей, на которых лифт не останавливается, и количество перемещений лифта соответственно. Во второй строке задаются K целых чисел l1, l2, ..., lK (-10^9 ≤ l1 < ... < lK ≤ 10^9), определяющих номера этих этажей. Гарантируется, что все эти числа отличны от 0. В третьей строке заданы N целых чисел, определяющих команды, которые отдавал Вася, находясь в лифте. Знак числа определяет кнопку (положительным соответствует кнопка "вверх", отрицательным - "вниз"), а его абсолютная величина - количество нажатий. Все числа не превосходят 10^6 по модулю.

Выходные данные

Выведите N чисел - номера этажей, на которых останавливался лифт после каждой из команд Васи.

Код проходит 82% из-за превосхождения лимита времени

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include<set>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<long long> noset;
    long long k  , n , curr = 0 , current = 0 , count = 0 , cur ,ioo;
    scanf("%lld %lld" , &k , &n);
    for(long long i = 0;i < k;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lld" , &ioo);
        noset.insert(ioo);
    }
    //quickSort(0 , k-1 , no);
    for(long long i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lld" , &curr);

        if(curr == 1)
        {
            do
            {
                current++;
            }while(noset.count(current));
            printf("%lld" , current);   
        }
        else if(curr == -1)
        {
            do
            {
                current--;
            }while(noset.count(current));
            printf("%lld" , current);           
        }
        else if(curr > 0)
        {
            count = 0;
            cur = current;
            while(count < abs(curr))
            {
                do
                {
                    current++;
                }while(noset.count(current));
                count++;
            }
            printf("%lld" , current);   
        }
        else if(curr < 0)
        {
            count = 0;
            cur = current;
            while(count < abs(curr))
            {
                do
                {
                    current--;
                }while(noset.count(current));
                count++;
            }
            printf("%lld" , current);   
        }
        printf(" ");
    }

}
```

Comment: P.S если вы не можете решить , то не надо ставить минус к нему , а просто зададите уточняющий вопрос

Comment: Спасибо, но мы как-то сами разберемся что нам делать.

Comment: Я просто не понимаю зачем это делать , если я просто попросил помочь и все

Comment: Я заминусовал т.к. не считаю олимпиадные вопросы подходящими для SO. Прошу не путать с ревью кода или конкретными вопросами по классу задач или алгоритмам. Кроме того - минус это повод разобраться что не так с вопросом, а не оставить комментарий характеризующие минусующих да к тому-же с рекомендациями по тому кому что и как делать.

Comment: вы имеете виду теги или  что - то другое??

Comment: задумываться не о чем плюс я прошу помочь доделать а не просто нагло прошу с нуля

Comment: Я имею ввиду что в текущей постановке вопроса вижу только желание пройти какой-то там олимпиадный тест. Пользы от такого вопроса ни для вас ни для сообщества нет никакой. Хотя его можно переделать в вопрос по тому, что я перечислил в предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: Если хорошенько прочитать условие , то понятно что они вводяться в первом цикле и вводяться не в масив а в set

Answer (score 0):

1) А ссылочку на задачу на e-olymp'е кто давать будет?
Поиском там этот "Нью-Донецк" не находится, и выглядит, как элемент спецолимпиады.
Вот за это и минусы прилетают.

2) Конечно, решение жутко неэффективно по времени.
Если одна команда занимает до 10^6 итераций над множеством из 10^5 чисел, то на одну команду мы потратим до 16 миллионов элементарных действий. Причём весьма не-кеш-френдли.

Что нужно сделать.
1. Отказаться от set в пользу сортированного vector. Этим мы сразу повысим дружественность к кешу.
2. Поиск осуществлять не по всей ширине множества, а начиная от текущей позиции.
3. Делать инкремент не поштучный, а сразу на всю команду.

Схема такая.
Пусть current - текущая координата.
Пусть pos - текущее положение (итератор) в векторе, такое, что выполняется инвариант

```
lower_bound(begin(noset), end(noset), current) == pos
```

то есть,

```
*(pos-1) < current <= *pos
```

(разумеется, с оглядкой на края вектора)

Если мы хотим сделать инкремент на +command вверх, то

- сперва возьмём, да и прыгнем без оглядки на безостановочные этажи:

  ```
  current1 = current + command;
  pos1 = lower_bound(pos, end(noset), current1);  // инвариант, однако!
  ```
- посчитаем, сколько этажей мы просвистели:

  ```
  command1 = distance(pos, pos1); // или pos1 - pos.
  ```
- на этих этажах мы не должны были лишний раз нажимать кнопочку, а мы нажимали; скомпенсируем (вот поэтому я назвал это число command1):

  ```
  current2 = curren1 + command1;
  pos2 = lower_bound(pos1, end(noset), current2);
  command2 = pos2 - pos1;
  ```
- ну и так далее, до тех пор, пока commandT не станет равной 0.

То есть, моделирование одной команды выглядит так

```
while (command > 0) {
  current += command;
  new_pos = lower_bound(pos, end(noset), current);
  command = new_pos - pos; // положительное или 0
  pos = new_pos;
}
while (command < 0) {
  current += command;
  new_pos = lower_bound(begin(noset), pos, current);
  command = new_pos - pos; // отрицательное или 0
  pos = new_pos;
}
```

Есть ли тут подводные грабли? Да, конечно, есть.
Если у нас много-много этажей подряд безостановочные, и мы прыгнули на самое начало этой серии, то new_pos станет равным 1. Инкрементируем command на единичку, перескочим на второй этаж серии, инкрементируем на единичку, перескочим на третий... И так будем поштучно ехать, пока не выедем.
А следующая команда, допустим, "-1". И мы попадём на самый конец серии, и начнём поштучно спускаться...

Что можем сделать в этом случае: заведём ещё два вектора, отвечающих на вопрос: где начало и где конец серии.
Тогда команда вверх будет отрабатываться вот так:

```
current += command;
new_pos = lower_bound(pos, end(noset), current);
command = new_pos - pos;
pos = new_pos;

if (pos != end(noset) && current == *pos)
  current = lasts[pos-begin(noset)];
```

А команда вниз - соответственно,

```
if (pos != end(noset) && current == *pos)
  current = firsts[pos-begin(noset)];
```

Понятно, почему в обоих случаях проверяем на end(noset)?
Потому что pos заведомо лежит в интервале begin(noset)..end(noset), где end - итератор конца, после последнего элемента.
Выскочить за передний край мы в принципе не можем, так устроен lower_bound.

Ну и нам потребуется предобработка - заполнить векторы firsts и lasts так, чтобы для первых и последних безостановочных этажей в серии firsts и lasts равны значению этого этажа, а для серединных - см. соседей до и после.

Заполнить эти массивы легко и просто. Едем вверх - протягиваем знание о начале серии. Едем вниз - протягиваем знание о конце серии.

```
for (i=0; i<K; ++i)
  firsts[i] = (i>0 && noset[i-1]+1 == noset[i]) ? firsts[i-1] : noset[i];
for (i==K-1; i>=0; --i)
  lasts[i] = (i<K-1 && noset[i]+1 == noset[i+1]) ? lasts[i+1] : noset[i];
```

Наверно, это даже можно выразить функциями высшего порядка из STL. Но и цикл сойдёт.

Comment: https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/3008 Спасибо большое!!

Comment: Только нужно проверить на предмет ошибок ±1. Я писал мысль, а не готовые куски решения.